# Web Scraping Python : Extract data without Tags using Beautiful Soup , Attribute Error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

My HTML page looks like below:

```
<p class="s3" style="padding-top: 1pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">(404) 365-6861 FAX</p>, 
<p class="s3" style="padding-top: 3pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">January 8, 2014</p>, 
<p class="s3" style="padding-top: 1pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 114%;text-align: left;">
```

I need to extract **January 8, 2014** from the html piece. I know how to extract data when tags are present, which is missing in this case.

What I have so far

```
date= soup.find("p",{"class" : "s3","style" : "padding-top: 3pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"}).contents[0]

print(date)
```

This works some times while working on debug mode, but throws an error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

So, I tried validating the input soup by

```
for i in soup:
        if i != None and soup.body != None:
            date= soup.find("p",{"class" : "s3","style" : "padding-top: 3pt;padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"}).contents[0]
            date = str(date)
```

But, still I face the same problem. Is there a way to circumvent this error ?

Note: I am running this over a loop on several html pages to extract the date. It works for a some but fails eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `get_text()` instead of contents:

```
secondNode = soup.find_all("p", class_="s3")[1].get_text()
```

Note that you can also find a node that has a text matching a specific date format, like in your case:

```
import re

soup.find("p", text=re.compile(r"\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}")).get_text()
```

Here a [regular expression pattern](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) is used to match a text of a node. You can also use a more appropriate [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) providing a search [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
from datetime import datetime 

def match_date_string(text):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(text, "%B %d, %Y")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Usage:

```
soup.find("p", text=match_date_string).get_text()
```

Comment: Thank you. That works but I still face the error ***AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'*** Also, the reason why I haven't used regular expression is, there were dates present in several places, but I need to extract this particular date which doesn't have a tag or title associated with it. However I would need to avoid either .contents or .get_text applied on None type.

Comment: @vamsikrishna well, which of the options issued this error? Could you please provide the other places where a date can be present on the page? Actually, the complete reproducible code example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Other places where date is present is `<h2 style="padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">
   Period :
   <span class="p">
    January 11, 2014 to January 11, 2015
   </span>
  </h2>` Also I have used `soup.find("p", text=re.compile(r"\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}")).get_text()`, I am running this over a loop on several html pages, so it works for some but not for all.

Comment: @vamsikrishna well, you can additionally add the class check: `soup.find("p", class_="s3", text=re.compile(r"\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}")).get_text()`, might help.

Comment: I was able to retrieve what I wanted now, but still the error persists. I have even put the code within try , except but still couldn't get through. `try: date= soup.find("p",{"class" : "s3"}, text=re.compile(r"\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}")).get_text()
                
                print(date)
                
            except(TypeError, KeyError) as e:
                print('')
                pass`

Comment: @vamsikrishna could you edit the question and put there the complete code you are currently executing? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116208/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-alecxe).